# How to get the maturity value from simple interest and the equation for it

Tags: java, math, finance

For the maturity I think the formula is wrong and it gives wrong answer. I just want it monthly. Maturity case is at the end. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package interest;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Interest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner whatKindPeriod = new Scanner(System.in);
        double principle;
        double rate;
        double period;
        double result;
        double periodNumber;
        String type;
        String matOrSimp;
        double matResult;

        System.out.println("find maturity or simple interest? for simple interest enter simple, and for maturity enter maturity");
        matOrSimp = userInput.next();
        switch (matOrSimp) {
            case "simple":
                System.out.println("please enter the principle:");
                principle = userInput.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter the rate:");
                rate = userInput.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("enter period:");
                period = userInput.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("is it daily, monthly or yearly?");
                type = userInput.next();
                switch (type) {
                    case "yearly":
                        result = (principle * rate * period) / 100;
                        System.out.println("your simple interest is: $" + result);

                    case "daily":
                        double daily = period / 365;
                        result = (principle * rate * daily) / 100;
                        System.out.println("your simple interest is: $" + result);

                    case "monthly":
                        double monthly = period / 12;
                        result = (principle * rate * monthly) / 100;
                        System.out.println("your simple interest is: $" + result);

                        SimpleInterest interest = new SimpleInterest(principle, rate, period);
                }
            case "maturity":

                System.out.println("please enter the principle:");
                principle = userInput.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter the rate:");
                rate = userInput.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("enter time of invesment:");
                period = userInput.nextDouble();
                double monthly = period / 12;

                matResult = (principle * (1 + rate * monthly));
                System.out.println("result is:" + matResult);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: For Java switch statements, you should  add "break;" at the end of the case, or you will execute subsequent statement. So you may see multiple print statements here. Regarding the maturity formula, what is the unit of the time of investment you are entering in ? Is it  years? can you give an example of the inputs and the result you are getting?

Comment: for example, im putting 11 but its as a month so i have to do 11/12 and then the calculation part where im stuck on

Comment: for example The maturity value of $700 at an interest rate of 1.5% p.m. after 4 months =  is $742 but i get something else

Comment: What is the "something else" you are getting? With your example, are you getting $3.5 rather than $42?

Comment: What is the exact formula you are trying to use to calculate the maturity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for maturity includes a compounding rate, so instead of:

```
principle * (1 + rate * monthly)
```

you should be using in general:

```
principle * Math.pow(1 + periodicRate, compoundingPeriods)
```

So specifically for your monthly compounding, the following method computes the desired maturity:

```
    double computeMaturity(double principle, double monthlyRate, double months) {
        return principle * Math.pow(1 + monthlyRate, months);
    }
```

A final note to remind that the annual rate has to be given in fractional value and not percentual (10% rate = 0.1 `monthlyRate`).

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/java/so/a59083054)

Hope this helps.